# emit firing multiple times from server side in socket io node js

Tags: angularjs, node.js, socket.io

I am trying to send a message from server to user but the user is recieving the message thrice. After researching, I found that the problem is due to routing. A new event is added for every route. I tried using removeListner(eventName, callback) but still the problem exists.

Comment: if u add controller more than one it can be, If u use angular

Comment: @esatilmis I am using more than one controllers.

Comment: i mean if u call same controller more than ones. for example u call ExampleController in $routeProvider and if u add <div ng-controller="ExampleController "> in your html, controller will called two times it just a idea

Comment: Its not like that.....I am using normal jquery to update the data on the page.

Comment: ok sorry i think that u use angularjs for this

Comment: @esatilmis No its not like that. Is there any way to solve my issue?

Comment: sorry i have no idea i am using ngWebsocket for that work but it is angular way